# Mapping entity type configuration with select stored procedures

Tags: stored-procedures, orm, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, data-modeling

Talking about mapping stored procedures on EF6 I noted that ModificationStoredProceduresConfiguration class only has three options to map stored procedures (Insert, Update and Delete)... (Code First workflow)

- Why there is not a 'Select' option?.
- Which is the best approach people out there are using to map 'Select' stored procedures to entity types on EF6?.

Thanks.